# Is it possible to specify bounding box or mode for thumbnails in the Dropbox Core API?

Tags: dropbox-api

[Dropbox's Chooser](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/chooser/js) API allows for developers to specify a bounding box and mode for returned thumbnails. The Core API does not document anything on this for their [/thumbnails](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#thumbnails) endpoint. Does this mean this is not available?

Answer (score 0):

Experimented around with the Dropbox CLI, mode and bounding box are definitely not supported by the Core Dropbox API.